# Weird animation when dismissing SwiftUI ContextMenu

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, contextmenu

After dismissing my context menu, my button has its border cut out weirdly for a split second below, before reverting to its original style as seen in the image below. [image][1]

Any ideas on where I’ve gone wrong?

I’ve tried meddling with the contentShape modifier of the button to no avail.

Here is the relevant code:

````
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct CustomModeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: WordBombGameViewModel

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State var creatingMode = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            
            ForEach(items) {
                item in Button(item.name ?? "UNNAMED") {
                    viewModel.selectCustomMode(item)
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1, pressing: { inProgress in
                    print("In progress: \(inProgress)!")
                }) {
                    print("Long pressed!")
                    viewContext.delete(item)
                }
                
            }
            Button("Create New") {
                print("Create New Mode")
                withAnimation { creatingMode = true }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $creatingMode, onDismiss: {}) { CustomModeForm() }

            Button("BACK") {
                print("BACK")
                withAnimation { viewModel.changeViewToShow(.modeSelect) }
            }

        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .center)
        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0))
        .buttonStyle(MainButtonStyle())
    }
}


struct MainButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.07
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(Font.title2.bold())
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5))
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
            
    }
}```


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwtUA.png
````

Comment: You may want to include a [mre] that people can use to reproduce the issue (your current code relies on a bunch of custom types that no one else will be able to compile) or at least include a gif/video of the behavior so that people can see if it looks like something they've experienced.

Comment: @Beetee were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strokeBorder` modifier instead of `border`.

```
struct MainButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.07
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(Font.title2.bold())
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .strokeBorder(Color.black, lineWidth: 5)
            )
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
            
    }
}
```